# Pass value from checbox to label in listview by delegate (xamarin.forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

[NEW PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O978H.jpg)

This is my first post so, be understanding ;)

This is my listview

```
       <Label x:Name="textLabel" Text="{Binding Text}"></Label>
       <Label x:Name="numberLabel" Text="{Binding Number}"></Label>
       <input:CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" CheckedChanged="checkBox_CheckedChanged"/>
```

Checbox: user choose how many items buy x1, x2, etc, passing by delegate "GetNumber"

```
async private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
var result = await DisplayPromptAsync("Question 2", "What's 5 + 5?", initialValue: "10", maxLength: 2, keyboard: Keyboard.Numeric);
  int number = Int32.Parse(result);
  GetNumber getNumber = new GetNumber(passingNumber.NumberOfProduct);
  getNumber(number);
  OnAppearing();
}
```

Here are method "NumberOfProduct" + "MyProperty"

```
public string NumberOfProduct(int amount)
{
   return _myProperty = amount.ToString() + " sztuk";
}

 private string _myProperty = null;
 public string MyProperty
 {
    get => _myProperty;
    set
    {
      if (value != null)
      {
                    
          _myProperty = value;
      }
    }
            
 }
```

Assign MyProperty to Number(field of Note class)

```
var notes = new List<Note>();
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(App.FolderPath, "*.notes.txt");
   foreach (var filename in files)
   {
     notes.Add(new Note
     {
       Filename = filename,
       Text = File.ReadAllText(filename),
       Date = File.GetCreationTime(filename),
       Number = passingNumber.MyProperty <------THIS IS MY PROBLEM
   }
            listView.ItemsSource = notes
                        .ToList();
```

[image: Here my input]

As you can see i chose "5" number for apple and
"MyProperty" spread for all labels and all my products have same value(5 number).
All I want is edit only one label when i choose only his checbox...
I try very diffrent ways (that i think)... can someone help ??
(i know about MVVM patern, but can I do this without it?) any clues? Regards!

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  I've read your post several times and I really have no idea.  Your code is a mess - why does `checkBox_CheckedChanged` call `OnAppearing`?  I **think** that what you are trying to do is 1) user clicks a checkbox in ListView  2) Dialog pops up asking for Number  3) Label in the row user checked displays Number.  Is that correct?

Comment: OnApperaing(); i use for "refresh" Page, 1) when user click on label he's add "Name of product" when click on chebox in the same label.. chose number of this product

Comment: you should not need to refresh the entire page when you change a few data items.  That is what data binding is for.  Why not just display fields for Name and Quantity directly in the ListView?

Comment: sory I thought so I do that directly? dont understand, code behind is unnecessary? –

Comment: Do you mean you want to refresh the listview when you choose the difference value of checkbox? If yes, could you provide more information with code and a clearly screenshot for us?

Comment: will it be ok if I paste a link to the git here? https://github.com/GrzegorzKononiuk/My_Projects/tree/ShopingList/ShopingList/ShopingList NEW PHOTO is on the top of post, this is the same project, only name of class is diffrent

Comment: I tried to download the file and extract. But i have something wrong when extract the file. i would check the code again and feedback ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok what I do

- remove property "Number" from foreach loop,
- add public property FileName,
- add Path.GetFileName

  ```
     foreach (var filename in files)
     {
       Path.GetFileName(filename);
       FileName = filename;

       notes.Add(new Note()
       {
         Filename = filename,
         Text = File.ReadAllText(filename),
       });

    }
  ```
- paste name of file(generated randomly) through "public property Filename" to checbox method
- using StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText
- writeline value(number) form delegate

  ```
        async private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, 
        CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var result = await DisplayPromptAsync("Question 2", "What's 5 + 5?", initialValue: "10", maxLength: 2, keyboard: Keyboard.Numeric);
            int number = Int32.Parse(result);
            GetNumber getNumber = new GetNumber(passingNumber.NumberOfProduct);
            getNumber(number);

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(FileName))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(passingNumber.MyProperty);
            }
        }
  ```

I hope this help someone, thanks for advice, See you soon !

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it seems like you are assigning the **passingNumber.MyProperty** to every item in the list:

```
var notes = new List<Note>();
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(App.FolderPath, "*.notes.txt");
   foreach (var filename in files)
   {
     notes.Add(new Note
     {
       Filename = filename,
       Text = File.ReadAllText(filename),
       Date = File.GetCreationTime(filename),
       Number = passingNumber.MyProperty //right here
   }
            listView.ItemsSource = notes
                        .ToList();
```

But that would be way too easy.

Comment: i know about it... well I give answer when i done this